# Is the Medrashic understanding at the Akeidah applied elsewhere?

Tags: words, midrash, genesis-bereishith, binding-of-isaac

In Bereisheet 22:2, Hashem commanded Avraham וְהַעֲלֵ֤הוּ שָׁם֙ לְעֹלָ֔ה to "raise [his son] up as a sacrifice." Rashi explains that the language was never that Hashem demanded an actual human sacrifice because that would mean that Hashem changed his mind. He quotes Bereisheet Rabbah

> When I said, "Please take your son," I did not say, "slaughter him," but rather, "and bring him up."

This requires looking at the Hebrew precisely. But very similar language is used in two other places:

In Melachim 2, 3:27 the king killed the son

> וַיִּקַּח֩ אֶת־בְּנ֨וֹ הַבְּכ֜וֹר אֲשֶׁר־יִמְלֹ֣ךְ תַּחְתָּ֗יו **וַיַּעֲלֵ֤הוּ עֹלָה֙**

and even back in Bereisheet, 22:13, after letting Yitzchak go,

> וַיִּקַּ֣ח אֶת־הָאַ֔יִל **וַיַּעֲלֵ֥הוּ לְעֹלָ֖ה**

Are there any commentaries which claim that in either of those cases, the object of sacrifice was not actually killed, using the medrashic understanding of the first use and applying it to the other cases?

Does the inclusion of the word "sham" change the meaning, making it the operative variable which allows for the interpretation in the medrash? Or is there something in the verb form or the context which indicates "only" raising up for a sacrifice and not actually sacrificing?

Comment: The purpose was to make Avraham think he was supposed to sacrifice Yitzchak, so HaShem used an expression which  ordinarily implies "bring up [as a sacrifice]". Nonetheless, strictly speaking, the expression "bring him up" is inherently ambiguous. As such, per Rashi and *B'reishis Rabba* ([56:12](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37457&st=&pgnum=150)), it served the function of causing Avraham to interpret it as a command to sacrifice Yitzchak, while at the same time not expressly contradicting HaShem's irrevocable promise that Avraham's progeny would continue through Yitzchak.